# Terminology for $B^{-1} A B$ (or perhaps $B A B^{-1}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

Given a matrix $A$ and a matrix $B$, what is the expression $B^{-1} A B$ referred to as? I think I've heard it referred to as "A conjugated by B", but I'm not sure.

(Also, is it more commonly $B^{-1} A B$ or $B A B^{-1}$? The [wikipedia page on diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) uses $B^{-1} A B$.)

Comment: Wiipedia is right, but in terms of group theory, $A$ is conjugated by $B^{-1}$.

Comment: @Bernard do you have a reference to a resource using that terminology?

Comment: You may have a look at this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class).

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) may also help.